# Obstacle Position

Tags: ros, position

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
Is it possible to obtain the co-ordinates of an obstacle that we manually add in Gazebo ? I want to write a ros node such that the user adds the obstacle initially and then the node obtains that position of obstacle from Gazebo and modifies its x-cordinate. Is this possible ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/215936/obstacle-position/) by [ktiwari9](https://answers.ros.org/users/18753/ktiwari9/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2015-08-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can probably achieve what you want by using the Gazebo services that are available when you start gazebo with ROS support. Once Gazebo is started you can do a

```
rosservice list
```

and you should multiple services offered by Gazebo that allow retrieving model properties, spawning models, moving them etc ([here are the srv definitions](https://github.com/ros-simulation/gazebo_ros_pkgs/tree/jade-devel/gazebo_msgs/srv)).

Most services offered are also described [in the Gazebo "Connect to ROS" tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=ros_comm&ver=1.9%2B&cat=connect_ros).

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-08-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ktiwari9](https://answers.ros.org/users/18753/ktiwari9/) on 2015-08-17**:
So in the Connect to ROS tutorial they mention something like rosservice call /gazebo/set_model_state to spawn a coke can at a specific location and orientation, Is it possible to do this via a ROS node ?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2015-08-17**:
Yes, you can cal ROS service from the command line (by typing "rosservice call ...", but you can of course also call them from code (see Python or C++ tutorials for "Writing a Simple Service and Clieant" here: http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials).

**Comment by [ktiwari9](https://answers.ros.org/users/18753/ktiwari9/) on 2015-08-18**:
Hi Stefan,
Please see my comments above. I uploaded my code and I have some trouble adding both pedestrian and robot to the scene. Could you help me out ?